VSCode, Pylance how to get proper help popup?
I enhanced a class by adding some few methods from another class (Jira's class from atlassian-python package)
My class is called JiraExtended.
Original methods from the class display this way:


The ones I created show this way with lesser info on function parameters for exemple:


The way I define docstrings is pretty much the same.
def grant_user_permission(self, username : str = None, permissionschemeid : str|int = None, permission : str = "BROWSE_PROJECTS") -> None:
        """
        Grants a permission to a user (username) on a specified Permission Scheme.
        :username: the user's username to grant the permission to, current username if not specified.
        :permissionschemeid: The id of the permission scheme.
        :permission: The permission key to grant, "BROWSE_PROJECTS" if not specified.
        """
        if not permissionschemeid:
            raise Exception("Provide a username and permissionschemeid")
        if not username:
            username : str = self.myself()['name']

        url = self.resource_url(resource = f"permissionscheme/{permissionschemeid}/permission")
        self.post(url, data=json.dumps({"holder": {"type": "user", "parameter": username}, "permission": permission}))

What's the secret so that Pylance guides me correctly?

The docstring format you are using is called reStructuredText/Sphinx, which expects :param username: rather than :username: (see also the tutorial). Is that what you are looking for? If yes, then this is a duplicate of How to document Python function parameters with Sphinx? and/or How to document a method with parameter(s)?.

Ensure that your type annotations are clear and consistent and all necessary imports for type annotations are correctly included.
def grant_user_permission(self, username: str = None, permissionschemeid: str | int = None, permission: str = "BROWSE_PROJECTS") -> None:
    """
    Grants a permission to a user (username) on a specified Permission Scheme.

    :param username: the user's username to grant the permission to, current username if not specified.
    :type username: str, optional
    :param permissionschemeid: The id of the permission scheme.
    :type permissionschemeid: str or int, optional
    :param permission: The permission key to grant, "BROWSE_PROJECTS" if not specified.
    :type permission: str, optional
    :raises Exception: If permissionschemeid is not provided.
    """
    if not permissionschemeid:
        raise Exception("Provide a username and permissionschemeid")
    if not username:
        username: str = self.myself()['name']

    url = self.resource_url(resource=f"permissionscheme/{permissionschemeid}/permission")
    self.post(url, data=json.dumps({"holder": {"type": "user", "parameter": username}, "permission": permission}))

